# Easter ornaments question

Tags: christianity, history-of-ideas

I know that there’s Christmas ornaments, but are there Easter ornaments? Have any been made historically? I’ve never seen them but that doesn’t mean that they don’t exist though.

Comment: Do you mean things like [Easter eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg) and [rabbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_Bunny), or ornaments like crucifixes?

Comment: Ornaments that are mostly religious in nature.

Comment: If you look at the links, you'll see that both Easter eggs and Easter bunnies have 'religious' origins

Comment: Christmas is a celebration of birth, Easter is about the crucifixion. People put on passion plays, do the stations of the cross. There aren't too many friendly images to have around the house involving torture and public execution.

Comment: "Easter is about the crucifixion" - One could argue that Easter is the celebration of rebirth; the resurrection of Christ and the coming of Spring.

Comment: ...and both were appropriating earlier traditions, winter solstice (as Jesus' birthday was almost certainly *not* in December), and the spring equinox (a festival of fertility). They not only usurped the dates, but also assimilated a lot of the accompanying symbolism (the evergreen, the eggs...).

Comment: See https://www.omaha.com/special_sections/from-lilies-to-lambs---easter-symbols-hold-special/article_fe75f253-6966-55c7-9580-53acdd014f89.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Not counting rabbits, eggs, etc.)

First, Lent is a time of penance, even more than Advent. It is not the time for beautiful ornaments, it is very understandable that it is more visually austere. some even [cover or remove statues and ornaments](https://www.ewtn.com/library/Liturgy/zlitur72.htm).

And Easter is not just Easter Sunday, the liturgy covers Palm Sunday and the [Triduum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschal_Triduum) (Holy Thursday + Good Friday + Easter Vigil on Saturday night).

As liturgical ornaments, I have always seen [Paschal candle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschal_candle), in Brazil, Portugal, and US. I have also seen some people using much smaller versions at home for private devotion.

Also, some people like wreaths, although it is more common in [Advent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advent_wreath). 
Some also take home the [palms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Palmsonntag_in_Osttimor_2019.jpg) from [Palm Sunday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_Sunday) procession, and use them as decoration during holy week (or just give a small one to children to play).

yes, ornaments are not so common as in Christmas. Maybe because lent, a [very distinctive liturgy](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/activities/view.cfm?id=1043) with the most beautiful liturgical objects and music as possible (as a child I liked it except for the long readings), and abstinence of meat is already enough to keep Easter in mind?

Or was it the exchange of gifts, the family reunion and the related media gift propaganda bombardment that did create the need for Santa Claus ornaments?

Passion reenactments are more common than Christmas ones. Not sure if it counts as an 'ornament', but it is a kind of public religious art.

And Holy Thursday has  beautiful ornamented procession, e.g., see the people [decorating the](https://g1.globo.com/turismo-e-viagem/noticia/comemoracao-de-corpus-christi-tem-tapetes-coloridos-pelo-brasil-veja.ghtml) path where Jesus in the Eucharist will pass. This one really should count as public decorative art.

Comment: That's a very good answer.   I would add that most Catholic churches have 14 permanent ornaments that people only pay attention to during Lent (in the form of paintings or reliefs for the way of the cross).  Also, for Easter many churches will be decorated with lilies and with white streamers (the latter usually not taken down until the end of the Easter season).